# How to get a name of a foreign id

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to get the name of my sub_id.

My table looks like this

```
    id  | sub_id    | title
    1   | 0         | Home
    2   | 0         | About
    3   | 2         | About Sub
    4   | 3         | Third Sub
```

So I would need the title of sub_id 2 which would be About. So far I've only been able to get the id and not the title

This is the select statement. The $id is the current page that I'm on, which would be About Sub.

```
select sub_id from menus where id = '.$id.'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using phpMyadmin

Comment: Your DBMS is... MySql not phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Make a self-join: Join the same table twice

```
select t1.*, t2.title
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.sub_id = t2.id
```

Comment: I tried that and I got this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't2.3' in 'on clause' (SQL: select t1.*, t2.title from menus t1 left join menus t2 on t1.sub_id = t2.3 )". It's not even showing the correct id.

Comment: Not `t1.sub_id = t2.142`. Use `t1.sub_id = t2.id`

Comment: Ok. I've done that and now I get "About Sub About contact contact contact". "contact" is another row in my table. And it also doesn't change when I click on other pages